# ListView wont refresh when calling requery() or notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, android-sqlite

So I have a database being displayed within a listView. When I delete an item, I'm trying to get the list to update and remove the item. I have all the code and am receiving no errors. I just doesn't refresh the list.

Here's what I have:

```
public void Requery() {
    db.open();
    final Cursor c1 = DBAdapter.getAllRecords();
    startManagingCursor(c1);

    String[] from = new String[] { DBAdapter.KEY_ITEM };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 };

    SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row,
            c1, from, to);
    setListAdapter(notes);
    c1.getCursor().requery(); //trying to refresh list
    db.close();
}
```

I have also tried:

```
public void Requery() {
    db.open();
    final Cursor c1 = DBAdapter.getAllRecords();
    startManagingCursor(c1);

    String[] from = new String[] { DBAdapter.KEY_ITEM };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 };

    SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row,
            c1, from, to);
    setListAdapter(notes);
    notes.notifyDataSetChanged(); //another way that still didn't work
    db.close();
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Why are you doing a requery/calling notifyDataSetChanged when you are already fetching new data from DB after deletion of the item?

Comment: Because the list doesn't update. I'll click delete. And the item will still be there.

Comment: Make the adapter one of the member variables of the Activity/Fragment and use that instead of the local one in your Requery method.